# How to change the sleep function of time module in python

Tags: python, time, dynamic, terminal, module

```py
from time import sleep
a = 30
text = ""
source = pd.read_csv("questions.csv")
questions = source["questions"]
for i in questions:
    try:
        print(i)
        text = text.join(i)
    except TypeError:
        pass
print(len(text) / 60 / a)


def plan3():#env):
    for i in range(len(text)):
        b = text[(i * a):(i * a) + a]
        print(b, end="")
        sleep(1)


plan3()
```

I am trying to make ^ work, but the screen doesn't update until I manually cancel the program with `KeyboardInterrupt`.
I believe it is due to the way `sleep()` is coded that makes it perform the function for the required amount of time, so I am unable to change this property.
The csv file has a database of questions, it can be swapped for a large string value and still it will not update "dynamically", if I am using the word correctly.
I need the questions to print like a printer, line by line on the screen on the TERMINAL.

setting `print("",flush = True)` didn't solve for python 3.8

Comment: Are you using an IDE, or are you using a terminal?

Comment: please edit your code and add a quote in front of `questions.csv` so it doesn't run into errors when others are trying to use it

Comment: I am trying to use this on terminal... IDE is working well...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I flush the output of the print function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-can-i-flush-the-output-of-the-print-function)

Comment: message = lambda x: print(x, flush=True, end="")
message('I am flushing out now...')
worked... Thank you... I'm not sure how to close this question though...